# How to load Facebook profile photo

Tags: java, android, facebook, view

I'm stuck on one problem... I try to load FB profile pic in Android:

```
        // Request user data and show the results
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
        {           
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) 
                {                   
                    userInfoTextView.setText(fb.buildUserInfoDisplay(user));    
                    profilePhoto.setImageBitmap(fb.getUserPic());
                }
            }

        });
```

The problem is, I get NetworkOnMainThreadException. Now I know, that I have to use AsyncTask, but if I do, I can't modify the view, because it was not created on that thread. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for network on main thread exception write this code before setting your layout file

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9(minimum sdk target that you have given in your manifest file)) 
{
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}